# what do you call intellectual creations?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe all intellectual creations? I came up with content but that's too generic. Artwork on the other hand has very specific connotation.
I need something that applies mostly to the realm of technology, but is not limited to software. I guess digital content is often the term chosen to describe that but I was wondering if there is another way to refer to that?

For example, for an author I can say something like:
Stevens King bibliography is extensive.

How do I say the same thing for someone who’s works include YouTube videos, software, research papers, maybe translations, political pamphlets, etc?
Is there a word to describe a wide variety of “works”?

Comment: Please see the [detailed help for this sort of question](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). I think we will need you to be more specific about (or provide more comprehensive examples of) exactly what you're attempting to describe.

Comment: Depends on your context: legalistic?  journalistic?

Answer (score 1):

It's called intellectual property. It's a legal phrase and carries with it copyright rights, royalties, etc., governed in the US by the US Copyright Act.

There is a huge body of US law on this that is very complex and requires lawyers who are certified specialist in copyright law to handle properly. If you don't want to protect your intellectual property, just say, "That's my creation." But watch out: Others will try to tell rip you off and profit from your ideas. And anything you invent is your intellectual property – songs, lyrics, artwork, software design. Anything. You can be sued for violating a person's intellectual property rights. It really is a serious matters. But those right have to be registered under the law.  It's not just a legal term. Laypeople use it too. I kind of like the phrase, "legal portfolio" although the word has no legal significance. There's nothing vague about your question so it needs no clarification. (I'm a licensed attorney by the way.)